# pvmove: "Insufficient free space" when trying to move mirrored LV

Tags: lvm, raid1

Originally I had two PVs `/dev/nvme0n1p2` and `/dev/nvme1n1p1` containing various mirrored LVs.
I recently added two new larger capacity PVs `/dev/nvme2n1p1` and `/dev/nvme3n1p1`, and expanded a LV (`home/windows-persistent`) to make use of the new space.

However, I noticed the LV is now split across all 4 PVs, whilst I prefer it to be on just 2 PVs, so I attempted to move the LV to just the new PVs with `pvmove`:

```
lvm> pvmove /dev/nvme0n1p2 -n home/windows-persistent /dev/nvme2n1p1
  Insufficient free space: 57793 extents needed, but only 0 available
  Unable to allocate mirror extents for home/pvmove0.
  Failed to convert pvmove LV to mirrored.
lvm> pvmove /dev/nvme1n1p1 -n home/windows-persistent /dev/nvme3n1p1
  Insufficient free space: 57793 extents needed, but only 0 available
  Unable to allocate mirror extents for home/pvmove0.
  Failed to convert pvmove LV to mirrored.
```

How come LVM is complaining of insufficient free space? How can I move the LVs correctly?

---

`pvdisplay`/`vgdisplay`/`lvdisplay` output:

```
lvm> pvdisplay -m
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/nvme0n1p2
  VG Name               home
  PV Size               476.74 GiB / not usable 0   
  Allocatable           yes 
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              122046
  Free PE               2812
  Allocated PE          119234
  PV UUID               n6vD1c-pF3t-mqlg-g4Ge-HPT7-FwOC-p7t6wK
   
  --- Physical Segments ---
  Physical extent 0 to 51199:
    Logical volume  /dev/home/dom0
    Logical extents 0 to 51199
  Physical extent 51200 to 51200:
    Logical volume  /dev/home/windows-persistent_rmeta_0
    Logical extents 0 to 0
  Physical extent 51201 to 89600:
    Logical volume  /dev/home/windows-persistent_rimage_0
    Logical extents 0 to 38399
  Physical extent 89601 to 89601:
    Logical volume  /dev/home/windows_rmeta_0
    Logical extents 0 to 0
  Physical extent 89602 to 99841:
    Logical volume  /dev/home/windows_rimage_0
    Logical extents 0 to 10239
  Physical extent 99842 to 119233:
    Logical volume  /dev/home/windows-persistent_rimage_0
    Logical extents 38400 to 57791
  Physical extent 119234 to 122045:
    FREE
   
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/nvme1n1p1
  VG Name               home
  PV Size               465.76 GiB / not usable 3.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              119234
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          119234
  PV UUID               1dmaeN-j0D3-EU60-kQg2-a5t7-CNdP-qpBYyp
   
  --- Physical Segments ---
  Physical extent 0 to 51199:
    Logical volume  /dev/home/dom0-mirror
    Logical extents 0 to 51199
  Physical extent 51200 to 51200:
    Logical volume  /dev/home/windows-persistent_rmeta_1
    Logical extents 0 to 0
  Physical extent 51201 to 81920:
    Logical volume  /dev/home/windows-persistent_rimage_1
    Logical extents 0 to 30719
  Physical extent 81921 to 92161:
    Logical volume  /dev/home/windows-persistent_rimage_1
    Logical extents 38400 to 48640
  Physical extent 92162 to 99841:
    Logical volume  /dev/home/windows-persistent_rimage_1
    Logical extents 30720 to 38399
  Physical extent 99842 to 99842:
    Logical volume  /dev/home/windows_rmeta_1
    Logical extents 0 to 0
  Physical extent 99843 to 110082:
    Logical volume  /dev/home/windows_rimage_1
    Logical extents 0 to 10239
  Physical extent 110083 to 119233:
    Logical volume  /dev/home/windows-persistent_rimage_1
    Logical extents 48641 to 57791
   
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/nvme2n1p1
  VG Name               home
  PV Size               <1.82 TiB / not usable 4.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes 
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              476931
  Free PE               457923
  Allocated PE          19008
  PV UUID               UzD83f-tnya-9wbR-TRrf-qkxe-2lf7-ewF3M7
   
  --- Physical Segments ---
  Physical extent 0 to 19007:
    Logical volume  /dev/home/windows-persistent_rimage_0
    Logical extents 57792 to 76799
  Physical extent 19008 to 476930:
    FREE
   
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/nvme3n1p1
  VG Name               home
  PV Size               <1.82 TiB / not usable 4.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes 
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              476931
  Free PE               457923
  Allocated PE          19008
  PV UUID               Rf7CoD-NxTs-ohO3-pqJx-dMZ8-6SCh-SXXhAf
   
  --- Physical Segments ---
  Physical extent 0 to 19007:
    Logical volume  /dev/home/windows-persistent_rimage_1
    Logical extents 57792 to 76799
  Physical extent 19008 to 476930:
    FREE

lvm> vgdisplay
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               home
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        4
  Metadata Sequence No  209
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                4
  Open LV               2
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                4
  Act PV                4
  VG Size               <4.56 TiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              1195142
  Alloc PE / Size       276484 / 1.05 TiB
  Free  PE / Size       918658 / 3.50 TiB
  VG UUID               1QhLGQ-ljr2-p0or-yAiD-530e-17n4-y8VN0d
   
lvm> lvdisplay
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/home/dom0
  LV Name                dom0
  VG Name                home
  LV UUID                XKpxWe-g8Rh-faKQ-s8Ht-KPC0-oLHc-tLneqN
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time home, 2016-07-02 18:55:56 +1000
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                200.00 GiB
  Current LE             51200
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           254:0
   
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/home/windows-persistent
  LV Name                windows-persistent
  VG Name                home
  LV UUID                4g6nXt-h6LL-YaHc-wfcU-Iote-rFJd-rpzgeF
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time home, 2018-01-08 22:18:42 +1100
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                300.00 GiB
  Current LE             76800
  Mirrored volumes       2
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           254:5
   
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/home/dom0-mirror
  LV Name                dom0-mirror
  VG Name                home
  LV UUID                WtfyuY-LRxR-nQBk-ft8C-T1gn-2hvE-TIQLgm
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time home, 2018-12-06 19:02:41 +1100
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                200.00 GiB
  Current LE             51200
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           254:6
   
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/home/windows
  LV Name                windows
  VG Name                home
  LV UUID                JKQjjn-4vUO-bwTD-eCl3-eZiM-mato-1R09It
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time home, 2023-07-06 17:10:07 +1000
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                40.00 GiB
  Current LE             10240
  Mirrored volumes       2
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           254:11
```

`pvs`/`vgs`/`lvs` output:

```
lvm> pvs
  PV             VG   Fmt  Attr PSize    PFree 
  /dev/nvme0n1p2 home lvm2 a--   476.74g 10.98g
  /dev/nvme1n1p1 home lvm2 a--  <465.76g     0 
  /dev/nvme2n1p1 home lvm2 a--    <1.82t <1.75t
  /dev/nvme3n1p1 home lvm2 a--    <1.82t <1.75t
lvm> vgs
  VG   #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize  VFree
  home   4   4   0 wz--n- <4.56t 3.50t
lvm> lvs
  LV                 VG   Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  dom0               home -wi-ao---- 200.00g                                                    
  dom0-mirror        home -wi-ao---- 200.00g                                                    
  windows            home rwi-aor---  40.00g                                    100.00          
  windows-persistent home rwi-aor--- 300.00g                                    100.00
```

Comment: Have you try to change the order in `pvmove` command: `pvmove -n home/windows-persistent /dev/nvme0n1p2  /dev/nvme2n1p1`

Comment: Yes, it produces the same error

Comment: What is the **current** result of command: `pvs`?

Comment: Added to the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to how `pvmove` tries to prevent reducing redundancy from moving two mirrors to the same PV (e.g., one PV should not contain both `_rimage_0` and `_rimage_1` sub LVs), the only* way to combine/colocate different parts of the same mirror is to move each sub LV one-by-one, and only by name.
Since the current error is quite cryptic, I've raised a PR to LVM to improve the messaging: https://github.com/lvmteam/lvm2/pull/126

* Maybe this can be bypassed with `--alloc anywhere`, but I have not tried

In addition to that, `pvmove` ended up having a bug in the very "allow parts of the same mirror to colocate" code that prevented it from working correctly. In the same PR above, I've fixed the bug

---

Ultimately with the above fixes, I ended up running the following commands to successfully move my LV:

```
pvmove -n home/windows-persistent_rmeta_0 /dev/nvme0n1p2 /dev/nvme2n1p1
pvmove -n home/windows-persistent_rimage_0 /dev/nvme0n1p2 /dev/nvme2n1p1
pvmove -n home/windows-persistent_rmeta_1 /dev/nvme1n1p1 /dev/nvme3n1p1
pvmove -n home/windows-persistent_rimage_1 /dev/nvme1n1p1 /dev/nvme3n1p1
```